# php encrypt decrypt with key in database

Tags: php, database, encryption

I'm simple trying to store encrypted email addresses and the encryption key in two separate fields in a db and decrypt it on a different page. Sometimes it works but it mostly doesnt.

```
function encrypt($string, $key){
    $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
    return $encrypted;
}
function decrypt($string, $key){
    $decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
    return $decrypted;
}
```

I've tried changing my key field from varchar to varbinary, didnt seem to make a difference.
Im on a schedule so all thoughts are indeed welcome
edit: here's snippets from my code
index.php

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DB);
// $crypter = new Crypter();
if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    echo "Failed to connect to MYSQL (".$mysqli->connect_errno.")".$mysqli->connect_error;
}
//construct string and mail to email
$email = trim($_POST['signUpEmail']);
$encryption_key = substr(md5(microtime()), 0,10);

//insert details into table
$password = $_POST['signUpPassword'];
$hashed_password = encrypt_password($password);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO signup (username, hashed_password, enc_key) VALUES (?,?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $email, $hashed_password, $encryption_key);
if($stmt->execute()){
    $encrypted_email = encrypt($email, $encryption_key);

    $row = $stmt->insert_id;
    //encrypting the row num
    $enc_row = mc_encrypt($row, '000');
    $link = "signup/signuser.php?u=".$enc_row."&&e=".$encrypted_email;
    echo 'mail link <a href="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a>'."<br />";
```

signuser.php

```
    $enc_id = $_GET['u'];
$enc_email = $_GET['e'];
//$crypter = new Crypter();
echo $id = mc_decrypt($enc_id, '000');

if((int)$id > 0){

    $validation = new Validation();
    if($validation->is_num($id, 'u')){
        $mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DB);
        if($mysqli->connect_errno){
            die('Connection Error');
        }
        if(!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT signup.enc_key FROM loo_signup WHERE id = ?')){
            die('preparing failed');
        }
        if(!$stmt->bind_param('i', $id)){
            die('binding undone');
        }
        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            die('executing failed');
        }
        if(!$stmt->bind_result($key)){
            die('binding failed');
        }
        if($stmt->fetch()){
            echo decrypt($enc_email, $key);
        }
```

Comment: If you know that it works sometimes and that it sometimes doesn't, you must be able to give us some examples of when it works and when it doesn't.

Comment: I just ran a test with 1 million random strings and keys, comparing with `$str == decrypt(encrypt($str, $key), $key)` and it didn't fail even once. I doubt the problem is in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

There is an AES Encryption Class, http://asirra-php.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/AES.class.php
which can be used like this:

```
function crypt_data($content, $encrypt) {
    include_once ('AES.class.php');
    $_content = "";
    if (!empty($content)) {
        $key256 = '603deb1015ca71be2b73aef0857d77811f352c073b6108d72d9810a30914dff4';
        $Cipher = new AES(AES::AES256);

        if ($encrypt) {
            $_content = $Cipher->encrypt($Cipher->stringToHex($content), $key256);    
        } else {
            $_content = $Cipher->hexToString($Cipher->decrypt($content, $key256));    
        }
    }

    return $_content;
}
```

Then use it like:

```
$encrypted = crypt_data($string_to_encrypt, true);
$decrypted = crypt_data($string_to_decrypt, false);
```